# Android FaceDetector always returns number of detected faces equals 0

Tags: java, android, face-detection

Android 4.2, Windows emulator with Intel acceleration.

I using this code and with different pictures always no face detection:

```
BitmapFactory.Options BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo = new BitmapFactory.Options();
BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565; 
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.face5,       BitmapFactoryOptionsbfo);
imageWidth = myBitmap.getWidth();
imageHeight = myBitmap.getHeight();
myFace = new FaceDetector.Face[numberOfFace];
myFaceDetect = new FaceDetector(imageWidth, imageHeight, numberOfFace);
numberOfFaceDetected = myFaceDetect.findFaces(myBitmap, myFace);
```

What problem is it?

Comment: hey there is no such error in your code ..your code seems fine ... have you tried  your code on any other device ...

Comment: No, I have no any devices

Comment: so u tested on emulator

Comment: hey i have posted a link... check it out

Comment: I try this code and got error: 02-21 12:10:33.886: E/(777): ERROR: Return 0 faces because error exists in btk_FaceFinder_putDCR.

Comment: I think on emulator we can't use FaceDetector

Comment: hey there is some issue when you use this code on 4.2 .... this code is running fine over 4.1/4.0

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24895/discussion-between-nipun-gogia-and-igor-kostenko)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example did the same as you did:

http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/android-face-detection-example/

Another link to try:

http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/face-detection-with-android-apis.html